# Calculate Yearly growth from monthly data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Station       A           B          C
Date
2013-01-31  1340381     1568766     910785
2013-02-28  1261806     1447467     843956
2013-03-31  1399123     1579597     926968  
2013-04-30  1395016     1618159     950947 
2013-05-31  1340408     1654265     988293
```

It's the total number of people travelling through each station, each month. How do I calculate which station has had the most growth(increase in no. of travelers) over the year in 2013?

Comment: What is desired output of your sample and why?

Comment: I am not sure of the output, the question I'm trying to calculate is 'stations have seen the most growth in 2013?'

Comment: I've tried pct_change() but it's giving me a monthly change

Comment: 1 year. The original data frame has daily data, but the I've taken a sum per month. The idea is to see which station has seen the highest growth in usage over the year

Comment: I have problem with formula - do you need `(df.sum() - df.iloc[0]) / df.iloc[0]` and then find which column has  `max` value?

Comment: Given your data, you can't find an answer for which station had the highest annual growth rate.  In order to calculate it, you need the total number of people traveling through each station from the prior year.

Comment: @Alexander - But if OP add rows from `June` to `December`, then is possible count it by `(df.sum() - df.iloc[0]) / df.iloc[0]` ?

Comment: @jezrael `df.sum()` gives you the total traffic.  `df.sum() - df.iloc[0]` gives you the total traffic for every month except the first one.  `(df.sum() - df.iloc[0]) / df.iloc[0]` gives you  the total traffic for every month except the first one divided by the first month's traffic.  If you had twelve months of data and traffic was equal every month, the latter calculation would yield a value of 11.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a linear regression and estimate the growth you would have in one year. Of course you would have a biased result towards seasonal changes since you do not have one year worth of data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df =  pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = np.linspace(1000, 2000, 6)
df['B'] = np.linspace(1000, 3000, 6)
df['C'] = np.linspace(1000, 4000, 6)
df.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods=6, freq='M', name='Date')

print df

t = (pd.to_datetime(df.index.values) - pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')).astype('timedelta64[D]')

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(t, df['A'])
print ('\nEstimated growth in one year of line A: ' + str(slope*365))

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(t, df['B'])
print ('\nEstimated growth in one year of line B: ' + str(slope*365))

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(t, df['C'])
print ('\nEstimated growth in one year of line C: ' + str(slope*365))
```